# Unexplained space space below xml

Tags: android, xml

What could be causing the space below this layout?. I can see an unnecessary space below it
despite doing wrap content etc. It is a layout which shows images and corresponding data some
horizontally aligned and others vertically aligned. I just dont want that space below it.
I cant seem to figure it out!!

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="3dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#D8E5EE"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/vp_slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:translationY="-200dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rentSale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_dots"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:translationY="-50dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vp_slider"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vp_slider"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vp_slider" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:translationY="-45dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvrvCategory"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.7"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:paddingStart="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/reddy"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvrvSalerent"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingStart="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/reddy"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:translationY="-45dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/subcounty"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingStart="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:text="County"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    app:fontFamily="sans-serif-black" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/city"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingStart="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:text="City"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlueJeans"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:translationY="-45dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/time"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingStart="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:text="Time"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:translationY="-45dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/url"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="start"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingStart="1dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                    android:text="Link"
                    android:textAlignment="gravity"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorNavText"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Set height of your constraint to match parent.

Comment: didn't solve thanks

Answer (score 1):

remove `android:translationY` of textview under linearlayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="3dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#D8E5EE"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vp_slider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
            android:translationY="-200dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rentSale"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/abc_vector_test"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_dots"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/vp_slider"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/vp_slider"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/vp_slider" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvrvCategory"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.7"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvrvSalerent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subcounty"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:text="County"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                app:fontFamily="sans-serif-black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/city"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:text="City"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
           >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/url"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:text="Link"
                android:textAlignment="gravity"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Thanks @Wini but unfortunately The android:translationY is needed for the slider dots. So it cannot be removed. 1 upvote for the RL hint